# Mercurial ignoring a file and I don't know why

Tags: mercurial

I have a new file which I am certain I added and committed in a specific changeset. However, looking at that changeset, the file doesn't appear to have been added. The file exists locally but Mercurial is denying all knowledge of it. It's not showing up as an unknown file either.

`hg status <filename>` gives no output.

`hg log <filename>` gives no output.

There are no patterns in the repository's `.hgignore` which could match this file, and there is no other `.hgignore` anywhere.

I am running Mercurial 2.1.1 on Cygwin.

Why is my file apparently in limbo?

Comment: Does `hg status -A filename` output anything?

Comment: > There are no patterns 
Are you really, really sure about that? Remember that patterns match any part the full path, not just the filename.

Comment: can you post your hgignore and what this file is named?

Comment: What Foovanadil said. The filename and contents of the .hgignore is kind of vital information to this question...

Comment: @D.Shawley sorry, I solved the problem before I was able to check this.

Comment: Even completely removing the .hgignore had no effect.

Comment: Any chance that you have `quiet = true` in the `[ui]` section of your hgrc file?  That will cause `hg status` to not mention files that are not in the repository.

Comment: It was .hgignore after all. Full solution posted in my answer. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by entering

```
hg add <filename>
```

After this, `hg status` caused it to show up with *added* status, and I was then able to commit it successfully. I'm no closer to understanding the root cause, but at least my problem is solved for now.

**EDIT**: root cause traced. The `.hgignore` contained this line:

```
out/
```

intended to ignore a specific directory named `out`. The trailing `/`, possibly combined with not explicitly setting the syntax to `glob`, was causing my file in a `layout` directory to match and thus be ignored.

I swear blind I tried removing the `.hgignore` file to see what happened, but I must have been mistaken.

Comment: If post the `.hgignore` file contents and the name of the file being ignored then maybe someone would be able to find the cause of the problem.  Also, someone suggested doing `hg status -A filename` to see what that reports.

Comment: Update back to the previous commit and type `hg status -A filename`.  It is legal to add an ignored file, so I am sure it is being ignored somehow.  `-A` will show ignored files in status.

Comment: It was the .hgignore file. Full explanation added to my answer.